# Error integrating Azure B2C in Blazor Wasm project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I've created a new Blazor WebAssembly project and tried to integrate authentication with Azure B2C using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` version `2.6.1` along with `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI 2.6.1`. However, during the project build, I'm encountering the following error:

> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I've already installed the necessary packages, but it seems there's an issue with the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App runtime pack for the RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this question?

Answer (score 1):

You had `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">` in csproj file so that you are having a .net 8 blazor web assembly standalone application. I can reproduce your issue by adding `Microsoft.Identity.Web` & `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` into my blazor web assembly app which is created by vs default template for .net 8 blazor web assembly standalone app choosing `Microsoft Identity` as the authentication type.

[image]

In this scenario, we shouldn't use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` because this is used for server side web app, but what we have is a client side app or know as `single page application`.

The easiest way to initialize the app is [following this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to register b2c tenant and create custom user flow. And then, here's a command for us to create a new project.

> `dotnet new blazorwasm -au IndividualB2C --aad-b2c-instance "{AAD B2C INSTANCE}" --client-id "{CLIENT ID}" --domain "{TENANT DOMAIN}" -o {PROJECT NAME} -ssp "{SIGN UP OR SIGN IN POLICY}"`

Comment: the msal packge might be what you need, I'm sure what you need is not Micorosoft.Identity.web  Since I don't have a b2c tenant so I can't test in my side for you, but the tutorial should help you do the initialization work.